# how to change aspnetusers table with another one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using Entities `User` , I want to change `AspNetUsers` with my own Table using MVC

1. `AspNetRoles`
2. `AspNetUserClaims`
3. `AspNetUserLogins`
4. `AspNetUserRoles`
5. `AspNetUsers`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: we already have full structure database and there is many different Fields and huge data in order to migration

Comment: highlighting code format